# Adding bonus to students score and should not exceeds the full mark

Tags: php, mysql, sql

There is a section in my school web app that allows me to add bonus score for all students of a specific class at once. The math problem I am struggling to solve is when the student got full mark and nothing can be add up. also the same issue happened when the total score valve will exceeds the final mark limit !

so, using the following MySQL query, how can I update all student scores which will not at any circumstances exceeds the limit.

for Example: course limit is 60 and the current student final score is 59 of 60 and we would line to add bonus of 4 marks to all students !?

```
UPDATE
    students
SET
    final_score = final_score + 4
WHERE 
    studentid = 201
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hint: LEAST() function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `LEAST()` for this, which will apply the smallest of a set of values. This will require your query to know what the max score is.

```
UPDATE
    students
SET
    final_score = final_score + LEAST(modifier, max_score - final_score)
WHERE 
    studentid = 201
```

Where of course `max_score - final_score` will be the exact amount to reach a perfect score. If that exact amount is less than `modifier`, then the exact amount will be applied instead of `modifier`.

---

If you want to subtract `modifier`, and avoid a negative result, you can do this

```
UPDATE
    students
SET
    final_score = final_score - LEAST(modifier, final_score)
WHERE 
    studentid = 201
```

Comment: Thank you Mr.GrumpyCrouton so much!
I just want to bring up the other scenario when we subtract the bonus back and to avoid getting -1 score, is it possible to use the same function?

Comment: @P.Coder Check my update

Comment: You made my day!

Comment: @P.Coder Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work for you?

```
UPDATE
    students
SET
    final_score = final_score + 
    (CASE
        WHEN final_score = 57 THEN 3
        WHEN final_score = 58 THEN 2
        WHEN final_score = 59 THEN 1
        ELSE 4
    END)
```

Comment: Thank you Simon K for the example, the bonus is dynamic so it could be from 1 to 10

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a homework question?

Clearly you don't want to give everyone +4, because it could exceed the course limit if someone scored i.e. an 58. But a student scoring 58 should get the 2 points extra right to get the max score right?

This means you can't filter student scores in the WHERE statement, using something like WHERE final_score < 60. Instead, try a way of using the number **60** in your **SET** statement so there is no way to surpass 60.

Good luck!